# How to create a queue class for queuing some lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, pytest

I'm trying to solve the-Eight_Puzzle using `BFS` algorithm. so, I needed a queue to store each state (e.g. `[None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`) in.

Here is my `Queue` class:

```
class Queue():

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    def enqueue(self, number):
        self.queue.append(number)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.queue.pop(0)
```

and I wrote a test-case to test this function using pytest

```
def test_it_handles_lists_correctly():
    queue = Queue()
    queue.enqueue([1,2,3])
    assert list(queue.dequeue()) is [1,2,3]
```

but when I run the test, it fails with this message:

```
=========================== test session starts ===========================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\code-ai\ai-eight-puzzle\eight-puzzle, inifile:
collected 10 items                                                         

test_helpers.py ..                                                   [ 20%]
test_puzzle.py ......                                                [ 80%]
test_queue.py .F                                                     [100%]

================================ FAILURES =================================
_____________________ test_ic_handles_lists_correctly _____________________

    def test_ic_handles_lists_correctly():
        queue = Queue()
        queue.enqueue([1,2,3])
>       assert list(queue.dequeue()) is [1,2,3]
E       assert [1, 2, 3] is [1, 2, 3]
E        +  where [1, 2, 3] = list([1, 2, 3])
E        +    where [1, 2, 3] = <bound method Queue.dequeue of <Queue.Queue
object at 0x028F5AD0>>()
E        +      where <bound method Queue.dequeue of <Queue.Queue object at
0x028F5AD0>> = <Queue.Queue object at 0x028F5AD0>.dequeue

test_queue.py:20: AssertionError
=================== 1 failed, 9 passed in 0.17 seconds ====================
```

can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Try assigning `[1,2,3]` to a variable `l` and then `queue.enqueue(l)` and `assert queue.dequeue() is l`

Comment: Programming your own `queue` class can be useful for learning. But in most other cases you are better off using Python's [deque object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque), which is fully tested, well-optimized, and generalized. If you are using the queue for multitasking, use Python's [queue object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html).

Comment: Hmm, Python has two queue implementation in the standard lib and you make your own, by wrapping a list without additional functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Queue` definition seems to be fine, however you have to fix your test.

Use `==` comparison operator in your assertion instead of `is` **or** make sure you are asserting to the same instance:

```
def test_it_handles_lists_correctly():
    queue = Queue()
    my_list = [1,2,3]
    queue.enqueue(my_list)
    assert queue.dequeue() is my_list
```

The `is` operator does not match the values of the variables, but the instances themselves.